# Flutter TextFormField causes error in Ios emulator

Tags: ios, flutter

I encounter a problem with my application when I run it under the Ios emulator. The error is caused by all the text fields in my application. I hang a simple example. I implemented the showSearch() function. The search box is not showing and I have a long list of errors.

````
   Voici mon code pour showSearch():

```

```

showPlaceSearch(BuildContext context){

  showSearch(
    delegate: PlaceSearchDelegate(),
    context: context
  );
}

class PlaceSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate{

  final googlePlace = GooglePlace(GlobalConfiguration().getValue('GOOGLE_API_KEY'));

  @override
  final String? searchFieldLabel = "Recherche un lieu";

  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {

    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

    return theme.copyWith(
        inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black54,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 16
          ),
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 16
          ),
          floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white
          ),
        ),
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: googlePlace.queryAutocomplete.get(query, language: "fr"),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<AutocompleteResponse?> snapshot){
        //....

      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: googlePlace.autocomplete.get(query, region: "CI", language: "FR"),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<AutocompleteResponse?> snapshot){
       //....
      },
    );
  }

}
````

Error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderRepaintBoundary object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: _RenderAppBarTitleBox#79ee7 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=278.0, 0.0<=h<=56.0)
...  size: MISSING
...  alignment: Alignment.center
...  textDirection: ltr
The constraints that applied to the RenderRepaintBoundary were: BoxConstraints(w=278.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was: Size(278.0, Infinity)

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp MaterialApp:file:///Users/user/Desktop/appMobiles/shaaplivraison/shaaplivraison/lib/main.dart:185:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2286:9)
#1      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2382:6)
#2      RenderBox.size=.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2066:7)
#3      RenderBox.size= (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2068:6)
#4      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:121:7)
#5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#6      RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#7      _RenderDecoration._layoutLineBox (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:903:9)
#8      _RenderDecoration._layout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1025:28)
#9      _RenderDecoration.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1317:44)
#10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#11     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#12     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#14     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#17     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#18     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#20     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#23     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#26     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#27     _RenderAppBarTitleBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/app_bar.dart:2159:12)
#28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#29     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#32     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#33     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#34     _ToolbarLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigation_toolbar.dart:146:31)
#35     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#36     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:410:14)
#37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#38     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#39     RenderCustomSingleChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:1389:14)
#40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#41     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#42     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#43     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1462:11)
#44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#45     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#46     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:249:12)
#47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#48     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#49     RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:451:14)
#50     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#51     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#54     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#55     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#57     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#59     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1462:11)
#60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#61     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#62     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#64     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#65     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#67     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#68     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:292:14)
#69     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#70     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#71     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#72     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1000:22)
#73     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#74     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:410:14)
#75     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#76     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#77     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#78     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#79     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#80     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#81     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1462:11)
#82     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#83     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#84     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#85     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#86     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#87     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#88     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#89     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#90     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#91     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#92     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#93     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#94     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#95     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#96     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#97     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#98     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#99     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#100    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#101    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#102    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#103    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#104    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#105    RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3735:14)
#106    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#107    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#108    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#109    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#110    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#111    _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:804:15)
#112    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1973:7)
#113    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:999:18)
#114    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:513:19)
#115    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:884:13)
#116    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:378:5)
#117    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175:15)
#118    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104:9)
#119    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1015:5)
#120    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:148:13)
#121    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318:5)
#122    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderRepaintBoundary#c67fb relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=278.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(278.0, Infinity)
...  usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
RenderObject: RenderRepaintBoundary#c67fb relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=278.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(278.0, Infinity)
  usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...  child: RenderMouseRegion#f07c6 relayoutBoundary=up21 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: <none> (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=278.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    size: Size(278.0, Infinity)
...    behavior: opaque
...    listeners: <none>
...    child: RenderPointerListener#6d3dd relayoutBoundary=up22 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=278.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      size: Size(278.0, Infinity)
...      behavior: deferToChild
...      listeners: signal
...      child: RenderPointerListener#343fc relayoutBoundary=up23 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=278.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...        size: Size(278.0, Infinity)
...        behavior: opaque
...        listeners: down, panZoomStart
...        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#4fce4 relayoutBoundary=up24 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=278.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...          size: Size(278.0, Infinity)
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
One of InputDecorator's children reported a negative baseline offset.

RenderRepaintBoundary, of size Size(278.0, Infinity), reported a negative alphabetic baseline of NaN.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp MaterialApp:file:///Users/user/Desktop/appMobiles/shaaplivraison/shaaplivraison/lib/main.dart:185:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _RenderDecoration._layoutLineBox.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:916:7)
#1      _RenderDecoration._layoutLineBox (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:923:6)
#2      _RenderDecoration._layout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1025:28)
#3      _RenderDecoration.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1317:44)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#5      RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#8      RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#11     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#12     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#14     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#17     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#18     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#20     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#21     _RenderAppBarTitleBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/app_bar.dart:2159:12)
#22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#23     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#26     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#27     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#28     _ToolbarLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigation_toolbar.dart:146:31)
#29     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#30     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:410:14)
#31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#32     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#33     RenderCustomSingleChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:1389:14)
#34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#35     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#37     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1462:11)
#38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#39     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#40     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:249:12)
#41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#42     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#43     RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:451:14)
#44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#45     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#46     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#48     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#49     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#50     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#51     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#53     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1462:11)
#54     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#55     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#56     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#58     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#59     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#61     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#62     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:292:14)
#63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#64     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#65     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#66     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1000:22)
#67     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#68     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:410:14)
#69     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#70     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#71     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#73     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#74     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#75     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1462:11)
#76     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#77     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#78     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#79     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#80     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#81     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#82     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#83     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#84     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#85     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#86     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#87     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#88     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#89     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#90     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#91     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#92     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#93     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#94     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#95     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#96     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#97     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#98     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#99     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3735:14)
#100    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
```

thank you for helping me

Comment: Try wrapping it into a `SizedBox()` and assign finite height and width,

Comment: I already did that but it didn't work